# Apostrophe in session variable

Tags: php, session

I have a select box where users can select their city/village. The input of this select box comes from a table containing all of the names. Some of those names begin with an apostrophe and when a user selects on of those, the rest of the name isn't saved in the session variable. How can I go around this? I actually need the full names including apostrophe?
Thanks! My code:

```
<select tabindex="18" name="plaatsnaam" style="padding:3px;width:235px;margin-left:10px">

<option value="kieseenplaats">Kies een plaats..</option>

<?php

$sqlplaats = "SELECT plaats FROM plaatsen";
$resultplaats = mysql_query($sqlplaats);

while ($rowplaats = mysql_fetch_array($resultplaats)) {

    if ($rowplaats['plaats'] == $_POST['plaatsnaam']){
    $select = "selected='selected'";
    }
    else
    {
    $select = "";
}


    echo "<option ".$select." value=' ".$rowplaats['plaats']." '>" . $rowplaats['plaats'] . "</option>";
}

?>


</select>
```

Comment: Where are you using session variables?

Comment: At the top of the page I put the $_POST['plaatsnaam'] into a session variable.

Comment: No, you don't.  You store it in a regular variable.  Either way, you should do some debugging on this to determine exactly where the value is changing or being lost.  Does `$_POST['plaatsnaam']` contain what you expect?  Does the variable you assign it to contain it after the assignment?  Is the value echoed to the page?

Comment: Dear david, I'm 100% sure I do that at the top of the page, it's just not in my code example. Note: everything works fine for every other name that doesn't contain an apostroph, but when a name with an apostroph is selected, every character after the apotroph goes lost.

Answer (score 1):

Always properly encode your output. With arbitrary strings and HTML as markup language, use [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities).

```
echo "<option ".$select." value=' ".htmlentities($rowplaats['plaats'])." '>" . htmlentities($rowplaats['plaats']) . "</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip, just changed it. Doesn't fix my problem unfortunately.